# IntelliJ JavaFX not opening window, not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am currently developing (as a hobby) Java Applications. Now I've wanted to do something with a GUI and so on so it gets a little more interesting for a common user.

JavaFX seemed like the best solution, but I've got a problem. I've started a JavaFX project in IntelliJ (predefined) which already generates a code which should produce a window with the title "Hello World".

As I have already mentioned, this doest work and IntelliJ just throws me an error (Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)).

Do any of you know what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, I am using Java 1.8 (1.8-0_161) and the lastest version of IntelliJ Community)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug of the nvidia driver: `Java SE Binary crashes pointing to nvinitx.dll`. Update your drivers

- [Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) JavaFX Application](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000060510-Process-finished-with-exit-code-1073740791-0xC0000409-JavaFX-Application)
- [JavaFX exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000143604-JavaFX-exit-code-1073740791-0xC0000409-)

Comment: Always look for an answer by hexa value, in this case - `0xC0000409`. These error codes come from native libraries.